# How to fix the error and syntax in this Timer program?

Tags: kotlin, timer

I am a beginner and wrote this code which generates two random two digit numbers and display it. The user need to type the sum as answer (in the editText) and if its correct, the score gets added by one and another two random numbers gets displayed. The entire program lasts 10 seconds (10000 milliseconds) and the user has to make maximum correct answers.

There is a high chance that my syntax might be wrong. I am new to Kotlin.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        object : CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

            var count=0
            var num1: Int = (0..99).random()
            var num2: Int = (0..99).random()
            var result: Int = num1 + num2

            textView.text="$num1 + $num2= "

            var inputval= editText.text.toString().toInt()

            override fun onFinish() {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Times Up!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                scoreView.text = "Time Up! Score= $count"
            }

            override fun onTick(p0: Long) {

                if (inputval == result) {
                    count++

                }
                textView3.text = "Time Left: ${p0 / 1000} Score= $count"


            }

        }.start()
    }
}
```

I expect the program to run for 10 seconds generating and displaying two random numbers where the user need to type the correct sum answer. The score gets added by one if its correct and next set of random numbers get displayed.

Comment: Please elaborate on the question. What is the error? What syntax do you want fixed? Are you asking how this code can be improved in general?

Comment: One change you can make to start with is using the [Random object](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/-default/next-int.html) to generate your two numbers: `Random.nextInt(100)`.

Comment: Error shown at: textView.text="$num1 + $num2= "  as 'Expecting Member Declaration'.

Comment: That line is problematic for several reasons. You can fix it by wrapping it in an init block: ```init { textView.text = "$num1 + $num2 = " }```
You might want to have a look at this article: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html

Comment: Furthermore, I don't think it even knows what `textView` is, you have to tell it: `findViewById(R.id.<TextViewID>)`. Same goes for `editText` on the next line.